# How can I catch a HTML/Iframe.B.Gen virus on windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, virus

Do I have to click ok on a dialog box (e.g. "Download this") or can it infect the computer without any action on my part (other than, say, visiting a site that has been hacked)?

Will being a non administrator user prevent infection?

Comment: Why are you concerned about this specific malware?

Comment: @gronostaj Because a computer with a malware detector discovered it on a site visited by a computer running windows 8.1 without virus checker on a non administrator account. I want to understand some of the possible attack vectors before I make any suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Comment: @gronostaj The question is not identical, as no infection is suspected or needs removing, though that question has some excellent answers

Answer (score 1):

I don't have specific information about this malware but;
Speaking generally, if your browser configured to allow running activex, java script etc. without asking, you can get infected by just visiting site. Most up-to-date browsers do not allow that by default.
Also being a non-administrative account prevents most malwares, but they can still be triggered to run if an administrative account logs in. Best solution would be running scans on a schedule.

Comment: So up to date software should be safe from this type of attack?

Comment: Yes, but also if *you* or *someone* did not change default browser settings, you should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows 8.1 and your security software thinks your computer is infected with an iframe "virus", it most likely is a false positive, or incorrectly categorized.  This is very common.

The original iframe exploit goes back to the Windows 98 era and [this vulnerability in Internet Explorer 5](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms01-020).  Outlook Express had a preview pane that use IE, and malicious emails used this vulnerability to execute pretty much anything.

Nowadays, an iframe exploit usually refers to just simple [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).  Your security software might detect clickjacking-like elements on a website, whether malicious or not.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML/Iframe.B.Gen is not (necessarily) a virus, it is just a piece of code!**

**[A quick lookup](http://www.virusradar.com/HTML_Iframe.B.Gen/description)** reveals that ...

> HTML/Iframe.B.Gen is generic detection of malicious IFRAME tags embedded in HTML pages, which redirect the browser to a specific URL location with malicious software.

In other words, it sees some HTML code in your browser that could be malicious but does not necessarily have to be malicious. It is not identified to be an actual virus, it could be anything.

This has already been catched by your virus scanner. On Windows 8.1; you often need to do an extra action to accept downloading an actual virus, unless you have in the past accepted some exception.

As always, keep your whole system up-to-date and ensure your antivirus continues to update and work.

Comment: Your answer highlighted my misunderstanding about this issue, that it is not a virus in itself, but a route for other viruses. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolute guarantee on everything even to a specific combination of virus and platform.

Anyway, best practices to avoid potential risk:

- Regular Windows Update
- Install a proper antivirus with regular signature update

If you suspect you are indeed infected:

- Do online virus scan - plenty from search engine
- Free scanner from various big provider - plenty from search engine
- [Recommended] Offline scanner from boot CD or USB,  may require some skills to create those media but cleaner result